# Is this algorithm doomed to be sequential? Can it be optimized somehow? (numpy)

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, numpy

My algorithm proceeds sequentially, from bottom to top of a 2-D array with just 2 columns, because the array is already optimally sorted, so it can just proceed sequentially from bottom to top (the sample code below is just random though). Therefore, the output of this algorithm is globally optimal, except that it takes too long, a few hours, with my real data (comprising millions of rows).

Basically, given a 2-D array, the sequence takes the first value (from bottom to top) in the first column (values are repeated many times), appends it to the results array, and then removes all rows from the 2-D array featuring this value in that same column, since it's been appended to results. Then it does the same with the second column, except that it lets one value repeats max 4 times before being deleted altogether from the 2-D array. Once that value has been appended 4 times, it deletes all rows in the 2-D array featuring that value in that column.

I highly doubt it, but is there a way to optimize this somehow?

```
import numpy as np

# Input arrays and concatenate them side to side:
input_A = np.random.randint(low=1, high=1000, size=30000)
input_B = np.random.randint(low=1, high=2000, size=30000)
inputs = np.c_[input_A ,input_B ]

# Results arrays:
results_A = np.repeat( float("Nan") , np.unique(input_A).shape[0] )
results_B = np.repeat( float("Nan") , np.unique(input_A).shape[0] )


# Positional index for 'while' sequence:
head= np.unique(input_A).shape[0] - 1

# 'While' sequence:
while head >= 0:
    
    input_A_item, input_B_item = inputs[-1,0],inputs[-1,1] # Take bottom-most values for either column and append them to results
    
    inputs = inputs[0:-1,] #Remove bottom-most row, as it's been processed
    
    results_A[head], results_B[head] = input_A_item, input_B_item # Append selected items to results arrays
    
    inputs = inputs[ inputs[:,0] != input_A_item,:] # Now that value from first column has been assigned to results array, remove all rows containing that value.
    
    if np.count_nonzero(results_B == input_B_item ) == 4: 
        inputs = inputs[ inputs[:,1] != input_B_item] # Same as last step, except this time verifying value has been appended 4 times already.
    else:
        pass
    
    head -= 1
```

Comment: results_A[0] and results_B[0] are both nan.  Are you off by one someplace (perhaps should be while head >= 0)?

Comment: You're totally ignoring the sort when you use a mask, and reallocating the entire array every time you apply a mask.

Comment: @MadPhysicist yes sure.

Comment: @DarrylG yes, slipped that one, corrected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process can be sped up significantly by:

- Not modifying i.e. deleting inputs during processing
- Instead, keep track of values we have used in column A and count of times a value was used in column B
- Don't use row if we have previously used column A value or have used column B value 4 times

Above resulted in an order of magnitude better performance.

**Code**

```
import numpy as np

def create_data(nrows, seed):
    ' Creates random data using OP method '

    np.random.seed(seed)

    # Input arrays and concatenate them side to side:
    input_A = np.random.randint(low=1, high=1000, size=nrows)
    input_B = np.random.randint(low=1, high=2000, size=nrows)
    
    return np.c_[input_A, input_B]

def init_results(inputs):
    ' Pre-allocate result arrays '
    nunique = np.unique(inputs[:, 0]).shape[0]
    results_A = np.repeat( float("Nan") , nunique)
    results_B = np.repeat( float("Nan") , nunique)
    
    return results_A, results_B
                        
def process_orig(inputs):
    ' Posted Process '
    inputs = inputs.copy()  # copy input since process is destructive
    # pre-allocate space for results
    results_A, results_B = init_results(inputs)             
                        
    # Positional index for 'while' sequence:
    head= np.unique(input_A).shape[0] - 1

    # 'While' sequence:
    while head >= 0:

        input_A_item, input_B_item = inputs[-1,0],inputs[-1,1] # Take bottom-most values for either column and append them to results

        inputs = inputs[0:-1,] #Remove bottom-most row, as it's been processed

        results_A[head], results_B[head] = input_A_item, input_B_item # Append selected items to results arrays

        inputs = inputs[ inputs[:,0] != input_A_item,:] # Now that value from first column has been assigned to results array, remove all rows containing that value.

        if np.count_nonzero(results_B == input_B_item ) == 4: 
            inputs = inputs[ inputs[:,1] != input_B_item] # Same as last step, except this time verifying value has been appended 4 times already.
       
        head -= 1
                        
    return results_A, results_B
                        
def process_new(inputs):
    '''
        Modify original process to keep track of values we have seen in column A and
        count of values we have used in column B
        
        Don't use if we have seen column A value previously, or count of column B value == 4
    
    '''
    # pre-allocate space for results
    results_A, results_B = init_results(inputs)  
                        
    # Positional index for 'while' sequence and results
    head= inputs[:, 0].shape[0] - 1
    results_ptr = results_A.shape[0] - 1

    # Column A seen, and count of occurences in column B
    seen_A = set()
    seen_B = {}

    while head >= 0:

        input_A_item, input_B_item = inputs[head,0],inputs[head,1] # Take bottom-most values for either column and append them to results

        if input_A_item not in seen_A and seen_B.get(input_B_item, 0) < 4:
            # Add value to results
            results_A[results_ptr], results_B[results_ptr] = input_A_item, input_B_item # Append selected items to results arrays
            results_ptr -= 1

            seen_A.add(input_A_item)  # add to seen values
            seen_B[input_B_item] = seen_B.get(input_B_item, 0) + 1   # update column of column B values
        

        head -= 1
        
    return results_A, results_B
```

**Usage**

Create data

```
nrows = 300
inputs = create_data(nrows, 0)  # 300 rows with random seed of 0
```

Run original process

```
test_a_orig, test_b_orig = process_orig(inputs)
```

Run new process

```
test_a_new, test_b_new = process_new(inputs)
```

**Check Consistency of Original and new**

```
n = 5000
inputs = create_data(n, 0)       # n rows with random seed = 0

orig_a, orig_b = process_orig(inputs)
new_a, new_b = process_new(inputs)

print(all(orig_a == new_a) and all(orig_b == new_b))
# Out: True
```

**Performance**

Timing using timeit

```
# Test Code
for n in [300, 10000, 100000, 1000000]:
    print(f"Nrows {n}")
    inputs = create_data(n, 0)
    %timeit process_orig(inputs)
    %timeit process_new(inputs)

# Results
NRows        Original       New         Speed Up Factor
300        6.56 ms         542 us        12.1
10K         160 ms         9.8 ms        16.3
100K        1.54 s        90.4 ms        17.0
1M          18.3 s         878 ms        20.8
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming, as you say, that the inputs array is sorted based on the first column (i.e. all equal values in that column are grouped together) then we can make use of numpy's `diff` and `nonzero` methods to find the last row in each group.

This also saves us having to build the `np.unique` array which is costly.

I took @DarrylG's already quite optimized `process_new` function and managed to speed it up by about 8 times further (about 170 times faster than the code in the question):

```
import numpy as np

def calc_method_orig(inputs):

    # Results arrays:
    results_A = np.repeat( float("Nan") , np.unique(inputs[:,0]).shape[0])
    results_B = np.repeat( float("Nan") , np.unique(inputs[:,0]).shape[0])

    # Positional index for 'while' sequence:
    head = np.unique(inputs[:,0]).shape[0] - 1

    # 'While' sequence:
    while head >= 0:
    
        input_A_item, input_B_item = inputs[-1,0],inputs[-1,1] # Take bottom-most values for either column and append them to results
    
        inputs = inputs[0:-1,] #Remove bottom-most row, as it's been processed
    
        results_A[head], results_B[head] = input_A_item, input_B_item # Append selected items to results arrays
    
        inputs = inputs[ inputs[:,0] != input_A_item,:] # Now that value from first column has been assigned to results array, remove all rows containing that value.
    
        if np.count_nonzero(results_B == input_B_item ) == 4: 
            inputs = inputs[ inputs[:,1] != input_B_item] # Same as last step, except this time verifying value has been appended 4 times already.
        else:
            pass
    
        head -= 1
    
    return results_A, results_B


def process_new2(inputs):
    '''
        Assuming inputs are sorted on column 0 in ascending order, we
        only need to process the last row of each set of rows having
        an equal value in column 0.
        Also, keep count of values we have used in column B
        Don't use if count of column B value == 4.
    '''
    # Find last row in each block having the same value in column 0
    unique_rows = np.nonzero(np.diff(inputs[:, 0]))[0].tolist()
    unique_rows.append(inputs.shape[0] - 1)  # need to add the very last row
    nunique = len(unique_rows)
    
    # Prepare array to hold results
    results = np.full((nunique, 2), np.nan)
    
    # Positional index for results
    results_ptr = nunique - 1

    # Count of occurences in column B
    seen_B = {}

    for row in reversed(unique_rows):
        input_items = inputs[row]
        if seen_B.get(input_items[1], 0) < 4:
            
            # Add value to results
            results[results_ptr] = input_items
            results_ptr -= 1
            
            # update column of column B values
            seen_B[input_items[1]] = seen_B.get(input_items[1], 0) + 1

    return results[:, 0], results[:, 1]


def generate_inputs(seed=0):
    # Input arrays and concatenate them side to side:
    np.random.seed(seed)
    input_A = np.random.randint(low=1, high=1000, size=30000)
    input_B = np.random.randint(low=1, high=2000, size=30000)
    inputs = np.sort(np.c_[input_A, input_B], axis=0)
    return inputs


# Original method
inputs = generate_inputs()
results_A, results_B = calc_method_orig(inputs)

# Further improved based on existing stackoverflow answer
inputs = generate_inputs()
results_A2, results_B2 = process_new2(inputs)

# Check results are identical
assert(
    np.array_equal(results_A, results_A2) &
    np.array_equal(results_B, results_B2)
)
```

Speed tests

```
In [130]: inputs = generate_inputs()

In [131]: %timeit calc_method_orig(inputs)
350 ms ± 3.97 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [132]: inputs = generate_inputs()

In [133]: %timeit process_new2(inputs)
1.98 ms ± 56 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Great improvement over my method.

Answer (score 0):

The *algorithm* might be optimal, per se. But is its low-level implementation optimal?

"Once that value has been appended 4 times, it deletes all rows [with that value]".

The above implies two operation: search the value in an array of counters, to determine whether it has already been appended four times; and deleting N rows from the 2D array.

Depending on the cardinality and distribution of the values, there are several strategies that you could employ (if the values are strictly monotonic, then you don't need an array; otherwise, you could use a Bloom filter or several other search structures).

Depending on the efficiency of the deletion (the low-level implementation of same), you might be better served by *copying* the 2D array in a new clean array, or adding a third column with a "deleted" flag and then copying the array at the end of the scan, or deleting in-place. The complexity of the basic algorithm will stay the same, but the time required might go down drastically.